# VHDL Input & output code

Tags: input, output, vhdl

I just started with VHDL so this is hopefully a pretty basic question, My problem is that i want to code this ciruit! --> http://postimg.org/image/rrd2czsox/ <--

In my ciruit as u can see, p and q both acts as input & outputs signal.
Here is my code for this ciruit!

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;


entity pracc is

port(a,b,s,p,q : in std_logic;
        y,z: out std_logic);

end pracc;

architecture Exercise5 of pracc is

begin 

p <= a AND b;
q <= NOT p;
y <= p;
z <= q;

end architecture;
```

But i can't compile this. Even if i change p & q as output signals!

Glad for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`p` and `q` are not inputs to your overall circuit - they're intermediate/local signals. Declare them like so:

```
architecture ...
  signal p,q : std_logic;
begin
...
```

Local signals connect logic *within* a component. Ports connect your component to other things.

Comment: Sure. Feel free to accept this answer if you feel it adequately answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

Declare p,q as buffer instead of input or output.

Buffers are outputs that are again used to compute other outputs.